# Tricky binding in WPF

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a list of countries and a list of translations in different languages for each country, this is available in my ViewModel as Countries and Translations.

I want to display each country and its translations in ONE datagrid row.

Each country may have different translations filled.

The datagrid I am using allows to add new columns at runtime.

I managed to show this using a multibinding:

```
  foreach (var language in languages)
  {
    Binding translationsBinding = new Binding { Path = new PropertyPath("Translations") };
    Binding languageBinding = new Binding { Source = language.ID };

    MultiBinding multiBinding = new MultiBinding();
    multiBinding.Converter = new TranslationsMultiConverter();
    multiBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
    multiBinding.Bindings.Add(translationsBinding);
    multiBinding.Bindings.Add(languageBinding);
  }
```

My question is: how can I set a changed translation back to my Translations list, by using a binding only?

Regards

Comment: You could either flatten your model so that it looks like: `Country|Translation1|Translation2|etc.` or you could consider using dynamic columns like in this article: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/891995/Dynamic-Columns-in-a-WPF-DataGrid-Control-Part or here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20719.wpf-displaying-and-editing-many-to-many-relational-data-in-a-datagrid.aspx

Comment: What would be a good way to flatten my model? I am using fixed business objects as model classes, and the only way I see is to make a mirror class with ExpandoObject